# Python regex to get everything until an expression like ''(year)"

Tags: python, regex

I have a data frame column named 'movie_title' which has movie names along with year. Following are two types of movie titles in the above mentioned column.

```
title1='Toy Story (1995)'
title2='City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants perdus, La) (1995)'
```

I want to split this into two columns with title and release year. I was able to extract years successfully using following regex:

```
re.findall('[1-2][0-9]{3}', string)[0]
```

Need help in writing another regex which can extract titles(excluding year info along with brackets).

e.g. title1 and title2 should look like:

```
title1='Toy Story'
title2='City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants perdus, La)'
```

Comment: Have you tried any code yet?

Comment: try your code out here: https://regex101.com/

Comment: I suppose the easiest way to make sure your code doesn't fail on things like `MythMakers Visions (1990): Jon Pertwee (1991)` is to not write any code, but you should probably try to write some code anyway.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen..i was able to extract years by using re.findall("[1-2][0-9]{3}', string). But, do not know what to do for extracting the titles correctly.

Comment: @abarnert...i did not think that way, thanks for pointing out. Any suggestions on how to pick it up? The above regex I wrote did not come up with two values for a single title, so I am assuming the dataset does not have such a record. However, you are making a valid point.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with your questions. Also, based on your response to Tim, I'm curious if you've read [Python's Regex HowTo](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#regex-howto).

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick almost:

```
.(?:[^\((0-9)])+
```

You just need to get rid of the trailing `)` that it doesn't capture. Will update this answer if I find anything better.

**Another thought:** If you are sure that the year will appear at the end of every movie title, why not just strip the last bit off? So remove `(xxxx)` off of every movie string you have?

Comment: Thank you! Can you please elaborate how did you come up with this regex? I am pretty new to this! TIA.

Comment: Of course, I basically go on https://regexr.com/ and play around with things until I get something that works well. Of course, knowing the basics of how certain character classes work definitely helps. But 20-30 minutes of playing around on this site and you will become pretty solid at it.

Answer (score 1):

to get the year and eliminate the parenthesis at the end use the regex "find the first string with at least one digit followed by a parenthesis" the regex looks like this:
'\d+(?=\))'

1.) \d means find a digit, the + infront means find at least one of these

2.) (?=) means followed by. \) means the character ')'. so (?=\)) means followed by a ')'

3.) putting these all together means a string of at least one digit followed by ')'

INPUT: City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants perdus, La) (1995)

OUTPUT: 1995

to get the movie tittle use the regex "get the first string with any number of non digits followed by '(' looks like this: '\D*(?=\()'

1.)/D means non digit. with * it means any number of non digits

2.)again we see (?=\() means followed by '('

3.) all together it means any number of non digits followed by '('

INPUT: City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants perdus, La) (1995)

OUTPUT: City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants perdus, La)

note: the regex for getting the tittle assumes there are no digits in the tittle.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> titles = [
...     'Toy Story (1995)',
...     'City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants perdus, La) (1995)',
... ]
>>>
>>> import re
>>>
>>> for title in titles:
...     m = re.match(r'^(.*) \((19\d\d|20\d\d)\)$', title)
...     name, year = m.groups()
...     print(f'name: {repr(name)} year: {repr(year)}')
...
name: 'Toy Story' year: '1995'
name: 'City of Lost Children, The (Cité des enfants perdus, La)' year: '1995'
```

Explanation of `^(.*) \((19\d\d|20\d\d)\)$` from [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/):

[image: explanation]

Comment: @Messa..please elaborate your regex

Comment: @shashankkumar I've added explanation screenshot. Please read documentation of the re module, it is all there: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html Basically I'm just looking for "something (something)" where the second "something" must be 19NN or 20NN. Both "somethings" are captured so I can store the matching part to Python variables.